# What is the Objective-C equivalent to Python's re.split()?

Tags: objective-c, regex

[Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) says:

```
re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)
```

> Split string by the occurrences of pattern. If capturing parentheses
>   are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are
>   also returned as part of the resulting list. If maxsplit is nonzero,
>   at most maxsplit splits occur, and the remainder of the string is
>   returned as the final element of the list. (Incompatibility note: in
>   the original Python 1.5 release, maxsplit was ignored. This has been
>   fixed in later releases.)

`NSRegularExpression` doesn't have this functionality. What's the closest thing I can get?

Answer (score 0):

The closest is probably NSString's `-componentsSeparatedByString:` method. It uses a string as the separator rather than a regular expression, but it's still pretty useful for common tasks such as parsing CSV data. If you need to break up a string using a regular expression you'll probably need something like NSRegularExpression's `-replaceMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:` followed by `-componentsSeparatedByString:`. If you need something closer to split(), you can write it in terms of what NSString and NSRegularExpression provide, and add that to either class using a category.